# Cordova/phonegap application with yeoman/backbone/handlebars/require

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js, yeoman

I've tried to follow this tutorials:

- http://www.gauntface.co.uk/blog/2013/07/18/cordova-web-best-practices/
- http://rockyj.in/2013/05/11/yeoman_and_backbone.html

to develop my test cordova application with yeoman and backbone...I've followed all steps but when I've tried to insert my first view the console gives me error about template...I'm novice in this and I don't understand where I wrong.

If I execute the code in my app source the console error is:

```
**GET http://localhost:8888/LABS_and_TRAINING/TEST/pgyo-test03/PgYoTest/src/app/scripts/templates.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1880
Uncaught Error: Script error for: templates
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163**
```

If I execute the code in the dist, the error is:

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'template' of undefined**
```

Here you can download the src(without the node modules)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2637840/src.zip

Comment: You should post the relevant code in your question rather than linking to a zip file.

Answer (score 1):

I was only receiving the "`Cannot call method 'template' of undefined`" error when viewing dist build. I came across the solution, but am not sure why it works.

Your RequireJS Shim for Handlebars should look like this

```
shim: {
  handlebars: {
    exports: 'Handlebars',
    init: function() {
      this.Handlebars = Handlebars;
      return this.Handlebars;
    }
  }
}
```

This solution is [still being discussed](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars/issues/48#issuecomment-17923555), but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the define block in your `AppView-view`, where you try to load a file called `templates`.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'templates',// there is no file called templates
], function ($, _, Backbone, JST) {
    'use strict';
```

This file isn't present so you get the 404. I assume you want to load `handlebars` instead, that you define in your `requirejs.config` block.

Comment: I think the templates.js file is generated by grunt during the build, in Gruntfile.js there is a handlebars task. Now if I move the generated templates.js from .tmp/script/ folder to app/scripts now the error is like the builded application:
Cannot call method 'template' of undefined